# Как залогировать только первые n строчек log4j?

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Есть код, который где-то выбрасывает ошибку:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


 private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

...

 catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("IOException occurred while method M1 was running  ", e);              
        }
```

В некотором месте программы логирует много сотен строчек.
**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы он логировал только первые 20 строчек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфигурации паттерна для строки вывода используйте `%throwable{количество-строк}`:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n %throwable{20} %n"/>
```